# User deletions do not get reflected across the parent-meta relationship

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta, deleted-accounts

A lot of things are carried across the parent-meta relationship for a user, but it appears that deletions do not. For example, if the parent account was deleted, you can still find the meta account by searching the Meta site's user list, as well as being linked from comments/posts. But if you click on the "parent user" link, then you'll rightly find a 404 because the user doesn't exist.

For the privacy of the user which I first noticed this with, my physical example will be someone else. Let's take user [4510](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4510) from Gaming. This was a spam account that was deleted on the parent site, however the Meta account is still alive and kicking. I'm leaving it alive so as to demonstrate this bug.

While I've only observed this on parent deletions, it seems most likely that a deletion of a Meta account would probably fail to carryover as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is on dev, and will go out with the next build.

Now deletions and destroys will attempt to delete/destroy any accompanying user on the child meta; should it exist.