# Ghost of deleted users left on Stack Exchange 2.0 Meta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, per-site-meta, deleted-accounts

Roger Pate has left, together with most of his user profiles. But strangely, a search for

```
site:stackexchange Roger Pate
```

turns up two instances of his profile on SE 2.0 Meta sites, on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/209/roger-pate) and on [Photography](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1467/roger-pate). Trying to access the parent profile here will reach a 404 page, so I presume it is *the* Roger Pate, and not someone with the same name.

Comment: This is because of the issue described at [User deletions do not get reflected across the parent-meta relationship](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70461/user-deletions-do-not-get-reflected-across-the-parent-meta-relationship). This has been since resolved, but old incidents haven't been cleaned up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At various points via upgrades, bugs, etc., the child meta API calls broke down here and there for brief periods.  Unfortunately, this happened when some users were deleted or merged...which means their users were forever left hanging around on the meta sites.

Due to some ongoing changes for project costanza I just noticed these today because they looked a bit "off" after a network-wide sync to child metas.  As a result, this account and a few hundred other orphans are all cleaned up now.  The few remaining on `discuss.area51.stackexchange.com` will be dealt with tomorrow (special relation case there...being area51 and such).

Comment: And can you tell us what project costanza is, or do you have to kill us afterwards? :)

Comment: @Benjol - If you look at your profile you'll see a "my logins" link at the top..that's the root of it, all your logins work on *all* of our sites (we don't automatically create a user everywhere, still).  As a result you get a simple account ID (your's is 6711 for example), which is in sync *everywhere* on the network, rather than a very disjoint syncing system we had before. Unfortunately for us, that means a *lot* of cleanup/change with everything related, inboxes, question migration, login itself, association, aggregation, `stackexchange.com`...and *any* old/bad data cleanup along the way.

Comment: so do we see that account ID anywhere, or is it more of a login ID that is only used internally? (And how come mine is 'so low'?)

Comment: @Benjol - Well that's a more complicated thing, but yes the plan is that you'll have a profile at `stackexchange.com/something/account-id-here` (which the network profile link in your user profile will link to) rather than that nasty GUID you can't really remember now.  As for being low...we back-filled the account infrastructure starting with SO naturally, so a low user ID there equates to a low account ID in most cases.